# How to override a Class property getter in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'v defined a base class and some derived classes, that will never be instantiated. They only contain class functions, and two class properties.

The problem is that Delphi demands that the property get method of a class property is declared with **static** keyword en therefore cannot be declared **virtual**, so i can override it in the derived classes.

So this code will result in a compile error:

```
    TQuantity = class(TObject)
    protected
      class function GetID: string; virtual; //Error: [DCC Error] E2355 Class property accessor must be a class field or class static method
      class function GetName: string; virtual;
    public
      class property ID: string read GetID;
      class property Name: string read GetName;
    end;

    TQuantitySpeed = class(TQuantity)
    protected
      class function GetID: string; override;
      class function GetName: string; override;
    end;
```

So the question is: How do you define a class property whose resulting value can be overridden in derived classes?

Using Delphi XE2, Update4.

**Update:**
Solved it with the suggestion of David Heffernan using a function in stead of a property:

```
    TQuantity = class(TObject)
    public
      class function ID: string; virtual;
      class function Name: string; virtual;
    end;

    TQuantitySpeed = class(TQuantity)
    protected
      class function ID: string; override;
      class function Name: string; override;
    end;
```

Comment: if `ID` and `Name` are constants for each class (getter-method only returns constant value for each class), you can use `Attributes` and mark classes using them.

Comment: Thats a new concept to me ... started reading abut it, but seems a bit more complex to retrieve the value than just using virtual class method

Comment: hm. seems I was wrong. It is hard to implement attributes (I don't know how :) ), when we have no class instances. Anyway take a look at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Attributes_Index Using attributes you can annotate your classes with, for example, `[ID('my class id')]` or `[Name('my class name string')]`, and then extract attributes values at runtime for those classes (objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you define a class property whose resulting value can be overridden in derived classes?

You cannot, as is made clear by the compiler error message:

> E2355 Class property accessor must be a class field or class static method

A class field is shared between two classes that are related by inheritance. So that cannot be used for polymorphism. And a class static method also cannot supply polymorphic behaviour.

Use a virtual class function rather than a class property.

Comment: So i should create another virtual class function, and call that from the Class-property get method?

Comment: @Bascy Yes, this would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didnt read your solution correctly, i understand now, just defining a public class method ID:string; virtual;

Comment: A class static method can call a virtual class method, but does not get polymorphic behaviour, because it is static. So the only solution I can see is a plain class virtual function rather than a property.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, can you expand on that please?  Surely any method that calls a virtual (class) method will get virtual behaviour for that method - otherwise, method invocation is broken.  Maybe I just don't understand your comment?

Comment: @DavidM You do understand my comment. The key is the difference between a class method and a static class method. A class method has an implicit `Self` reference to a class. A static class method does not contain a `Self` reference. In effect a static class method is equivalent to a procedure or function that is declared outside a class. No polymorphism there. All this means that when a static class method invokes a virtual method, it does not get virtual dispatch. The method invocation is known at compile time and there is no polymorphism.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks for explaining!  How do virtual class methods work at all, then?  I had guessed the equivalent of Self would be a reference to the metaclass, so virtual dispatch for class methods would still function.  When you call a virtual class method from within an instance method, does it pass Self to the class method referring to the instance, not the class/metaclass?

Comment: @david the Self for a virtual class method refers to a class

Comment: Oh, I get it.  Static class methods don't have a reference to the class at all (Self) - exactly what you said, I just didn't understand.  Seems a real shame!

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  // Abstraction is used at sample to omit implementation
  TQuantity = class abstract
  protected
    class function GetID: string; virtual; abstract;
    class procedure SetID(const Value: string); virtual; abstract;
  public
    // Delphi compiler understands class getters and setters
    {class} property ID: string read GetID write SetID;
  end;

var
  Quantity: TQuantity;

begin
  Quantity.ID := '?';
```